# Import SQL dumps trough bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to import GZiped MySQL databases listed in a folder.

GZiped files are located at `.mysqldumps/`.

`$NAME` tries to extract database name *(as files are always named `database_name.sql.gz`)* and pass it to `mysql` command line.

Also, as username and database name are the same, the same argument is passed (`$NAME`).

As files are GZiped, we try to `zcat` them *(so `gunzip -c`)* before pipe them to `mysql`.

**The full script is:**

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES='.mysqldumps/*'
PASSWORD='MyPassword'

for f in $FILES
do
    NAME=dbprefix_`basename $f .sql.gz`
    echo "Processing $f"
    set -x
    zcat $f | mysql -u "$NAME" -p$PASSWORD "$NAME"
done
```

But, when i run the script it outputs:

```
./.mysqlimport
Processing .mysqldumps/first_database.sql.gz
+ mysql -u dbprefix_first_database -pMyPassword dbprefix_first_database
+ zcat .mysqldumps/first_database.sql.gz
ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 22: Access denied for user 'dbprefix_first_database'@'localhost' to database 'first_database'
```

As you can see, the selected database is `'first_database'` instead of `'dbprefix_first_database'` and this just trowns an error of corse, and i just can't understand why `$NAME` is not correctly parse as database name.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're passing `$NAME` as listed? What if you specify `-D $NAME`?

Comment: Yes i'm sure. Same result with `-D $NAME`. And as you can see, `$NAME` is parsed as `dbprefix_first_database` in the first place (username) but not at the second place (database name).

Comment: And if i replace `$NAME` with something like `testing_fixed_dbname`:

`ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'dbprefix_first_database'@'localhost' to database 'testing_fixed_dbname'`

So the problem here is the arg, but i just can't understand why.

Comment: There's something missing in your description of the problem. What you describe doesn't make sense. Use `set -x` to see exactly what command is being executed.

Comment: I've edited and try to make things more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, the problem comes from the DUMP and not from the script.

While using `mysqldump` the option `--databases` was used which includes the `USE 'dbname';` and when importing, that name was used instead of `$NAME`.

Problem solved!